# How can I load a div content from a php page into another div in a html page?

Tags: php, html, jquery

I have 2 webpages.

1. home.php
2. side.html

In the home.php page,
I have the following jQuery Ajax function fetching data from MySQL table:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "display.php", 
                method: "POST", 
                data:{ 
                        beginner:sel_beginner,
                        marks:sel_marks, 
                        formID_Selected:formIdSelected, 
                        sel_topicID:topicIdSelected
                          },   
                success:function(data){ 
                    $("#quizzes").html(data);
                        }
                    }); 
};
  }
```

The result of this function is successfully displayed in a div on the home.php.
Now, I'm trying to get the results of this function in another div in the second webpage (side.html) page, but I can't get it through for some reason.
I've tried the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnApply").click(function() {
    window.open("side.html");
  })
});
```

On the side.html side, I've got the following:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
    $( "#questions" ).load("home.php #questionList" );
    console.log(questions);
  });
```

But I'm completely stuck.
I would appreciate any help towards my endeavor.

Comment: You trying to feed content you have available on home.php to side.html while using display.php to retrieve the content from the database? Honestly sounds like you need to refactor some.

AJAX (XMLHttpRequest or Fetch API) only thing I can find that might fit your need

Comment: When you load home.php from side.html that's a new request, and home.php is fetched directly from the server. It won't contain any content in home.php which it itself loaded via JavaScript code, because there's no browser context in which to execute it. But why do you need to do this anyway? If the data is already visible in home.php, why do you want to show it again in another page?

Comment: @ADyson thank you for your feedback. I need this data to show up in side.html to convert to pdf using react.js. 
Let me know if there are other options to achieve this.

Comment: Why not do the conversion in home.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**localStorage / sessionStorage**

I decided to use localStorage
Set an item on home.php like so:

```
localStorage.setItem('data', 'content');
```

Retrieve the item on side.html :

```
let mPage = localStorage.getItem('data');
```

If you are dealing with object or arrays, you need to serialize them:

```
json.stringify();
```

And then deserialize on side.html like:

```
json.parse();
```

Great for your tips.